# Wordpress skip latest "x" number of post

Tags: wordpress, post

I want do skip latest 4 post.Is it possible bottom loop? I tried off-set property but doesnt work like i want.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=2'); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


                <div class="col-md-12" >
<div class="res">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(array(200,200) ); ?> " alt="Norway" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
                <div class="bottom"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
                <div class="top-left">   
<?php 
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){

        $cat_link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID);
   echo '<a href="'.$cat_link.'"> '.$category-> name.'</a>';

        }
    ?> 
    </div>
            </div>

                    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>

                <!--. entry-->
                </div>

            </div><!-- .post-->

        <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
        <?php else : ?>

        <?php endif; ?></div>
```

I want do skip latest 4 post.Is it possible bottom loop? I tried off-set property but doesnt work like i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip latest posts by simply changing the get_posts function parameters, adding the parameter **offset** .

Your code would look like:
    query_posts('posts_per_page=2&offset=3')

Where **offset=3** states that you want to skip first 3 posts.

More in detail information on the following article:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-exclude-latest-post-from-the-wordpress-post-loop/